# Database connection not working when called through wcf service

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf, exception

My application has a DAL layer with a working local database. I have tests interacting with the db and they work fine.

I also have a wcf service that uses the functions provided by my DAL. However, when the client application calls the service, no data gets retrieved. Instead, I get an exception:

> Message = "The underlying provider failed on Open."
>
> "System.Data.Entity"
>
> StackTrace = "at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
>   Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)\r\n  ...

With an inner exception:

> "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."
>
> {"No such host is known"}
>
> "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings)\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
>   openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
>   originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
>   Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)"

I verified that my connection string is the same as what my tests use.

```
<add name="loansEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/LoansDbModel.csdl|res://*/LoansDbModel.ssdl|res://*/LoansDbModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost:3306;User Id=root;password=123456;database=dbname;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

The database is a local mysql database, the user and database both exist.
The services are also local, running in IIS Express.

Why am I getting this exception?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to several reasons please check below points:

- If you are using `System.Data.SqlClient` in your connection then change
  it to `System.Data.Odbc`
- Check database name
- Check you port is open or not. (probably 3306)
- Change your bind-address in your my.ini file (from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0)
- Check the user your trying to connect to server has necessary privileges

Comment: Please use this connection string Server=localhost;Port=3309;Database=Test;Uid=username;Pwd=password;  Please change port ,database,userid and password and try it !

Comment: The correct connection string for MySQL ADO.NET Connector is

Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=Test;Uid=username;Pwd=password;

Comment: I get "Keyword is not supported: port."

Comment: Can you help me to figure out the source of this error? Where do you specify loansEntities as the connection string to be used in your C# code?

Comment: I have it both in the wcf service web.config and in my tests. The tests work, but the service doesn't.